# Parsing Json Show Error keyNotFound Swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, parsing

i want to Parsing a json but Xcode Show this message : **keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "Id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Id\", intValue: nil) (\"Id\").", underlyingError: nil))**

JSON :

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "Id": 5,
            "Title": "Test1",
            "EnTitle": "Story and Novel"
        },
        {
            "Id": 38,
            "Title": "Test2",
            "EnTitle": " Motivational"
        }

    ],
    "status": {
        "message": "Confirm",
        "success": true,
        "systemDateTime": "2019-11-01T12:07:05+03:30",
        "httpStatusCode": 200
    }
}
```

Model :

```
struct Result : Decodable {
    let Id : Int
    let Title : String
    let EnTitle : String
}

class ResultInitialiser {

    let Id : Int
    let Title : String
    let EnTitle : String

    init(Id:Int, Title:String, EnTitle: String) {
        self.Id = Id
        self.Title = Title
        self.EnTitle = EnTitle
    }

}
```

View Controller :

```
var genresFetch = [Result]()
var structGenresFetch = [ResultInitialiser]()
let headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Token" : "6f8652e3-d9d9-4b34-9455-0fa32e82ec58"]

    AF.request(BASE_URL!, method: .get, headers: headers).response { (response) in
        do {
            self.genresFetch = [try JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: response.data!)]

                for eachProduct in self.genresFetch {

                    let recived_Data = ResultInitialiser(Id: eachProduct.Id, Title: eachProduct.Title, EnTitle: eachProduct.EnTitle)
                    self.structGenresFetch.append(recived_Data)
                    print(eachProduct.Title)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.tvMainApi.reloadData()
                    }
                }
        }catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: please remove `class ResultInitialiser` it's a ducplication of `Result`

Answer (score 0):

> "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"Id\", intValue: nil)

The root of the json contains `result` key only and doesn't have id or the other keys you submit with your `Result` struct , so You need

```
self.genresFetch = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: response.data!)
print(self.genresFetch.result)
```

---

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let result : [Result]

}

struct Result: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let title, enTitle: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "Id"
        case title = "Title"
        case enTitle = "EnTitle"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSONDecoder` will try to decode the JSON from the root. At the root level, there are only two keys, `results` and `status`. The `Decodable` type that you have passed to it, `Result`, has neither of those keys.

You need to create another struct:

```
struct Response {
    let results: [Result]
}
```

And decode this struct instead:

```
    do {
        // notice the change to this line
        self.genresFetch = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: response.data!).results
        ...
    }catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

IMO, you don't need the extra `class` called `ResultInitialiser`. What's wrong with just using the struct as your model?